# How to use U+E133 as an AppBarCommand.icon?

Tags: winjs, appbar

I want to use the U+E133 (or ) from the Sergoe UI Symbol font in my AppBarCommand:

```
<button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmdEnableMarkFriends', label:'Select', icon:'\E133'}" type="button"></button>
```

This icon [image: U+E133] is the same icon the mail app uses in it's AppBar to enable the selection. I already searched the web for more comprehensive enumeration list, but I couldn't find this specific icon.

Is there a name for this icon or a way to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the name of This icon. It is **bullets**.